# Change the height of a TableViewCell depending on if it has an image

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I have a tableview that has tableview cells that are populated with users posts on the app. users are able to have posts with just text or they can include an image with their text.

The problem i have is with setting the cell height depending on if the post contains an image. for example if the post contains an image i want the cell height = 400 but if it contains only text then i want the cell height = 150.

At the moment i have the height fixed at 400 using this code but i don't know how to make the above modifications.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //auto cell height
    return 400
    
}
```

post model looks like this...

```
class Posts {
var id: String
var author: String
var text: String
var createdAt: Date
var degree: String
var university: String
var uid: String
var photoURL: String
var url: URL
var postID: String
var likes: Int

init(id:String, author:String, text:String, timestamp:Double, degree:String, university:String, uid:String, photoURL:String, url:URL, postID:String, likes:Int) {
    self.id = id
    self.author = author
    self.text = text
    self.createdAt = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp / 1000)
    self.degree = degree 
    self.university = university
    self.uid = uid
    self.photoURL = photoURL
    self.url = url
    self.postID = postID
    self.likes = likes
    
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a custom TableViewCell? Because you could always design a custom cell with an image (and adjust the constraints accordingly) and just hide the imageView if there is no image to put in there.

Comment: Ok this sounds like a good idea. what will i set for the tableView heightForRowAt function? so that it works when there is an image and when there isnt

Comment: You actually shouldn't need to set that function at all. There are a few auto layout things you need to pay attention to (see my answer below because I couldn't fit it all in this comment), but if you do it right, the cell should be able to resize itself without that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding this code to the tableview cellforrowat index path function in order to get the images rendering correctly.

```
let imageIndex = posts[indexPath.row].mediaURL
            let url = NSURL(string: imageIndex)! as URL
            if let imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
               let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                let newWidth = cell.MediaPhoto.frame.width
                let scale = newWidth/image!.size.width
                let newHeight = image!.size.height * scale
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
                image!.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
                    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                    cell.MediaPhoto.image = newImage
                cell.MediaPhoto.contentMode = .scaleToFill
                cell.MediaPhoto.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

One decently easy way to do this is to create a custom view cell and hide the imageView if needed.

Create the custom tableView cell and make sure to add a .xib file to be able to edit everything visually:

[image: Make sure to create a .xib file to help with the next steps.]

Set the row height to automatic so that the tableView knows to set the height to whatever you need.
[image: Set the row height to automatic]

Then, you can add your text and imageView onto this custom cell. The way I've gotten this to work before is to add both elements into a stackView and set up constraints on that.

[image: set correct autolayouts]

**Make sure you have constraints set up for the height the label and imageView inside of the stackView and the distance from the stackView to the bottom and top of the superView. This lets auto layout know how tall to make the cell**

Now, any time you hide the imageView (when you don't have an image to display) the cell should autoresize to be smaller.